# Is there a chrome tool that will extract AND export all rules applying to an element and its contents?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors

For instance, while trying to duplicate some styling from a site I'm working on to another page in the site, but not pull in all the other X^N selectors I'd like to grab just those that apply to a particular element and it's children.

Is there a chrome tool that will extract AND export all rules applying to an element and its contents?